# html botões menu dropdown

Tags: html, submenu

Tenho um menu com drop down e ao passar o rato para a segunda hipótese ele desaparece.

```
     <nav>
  <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a>
                <ul>
                      <li><a href="#">Quem Somos?</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Missão e Valores</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Actividades</a></li>                   
                </ul>
            </li>
        <li><a href="#">Seguridad Suministro</a>
        <ul>
                      <li><a href="#">Produtos petroliferos</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">GPL</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Gás Natural</a></li>                       
                      <li><a href="#">Internacional</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Finanzas</a>
                <ul>
                      <li><a href="#">Financiacion</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Informações Financeiras</a></li>

                </ul>
            </li>
        <li><a href="#">Normativa</a> 
        <ul>
                      <li><a href="#">Normativa Internacional</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Normativa Nacional</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Normativa Sectorial</a></li>                   
                </ul>
            </li>
        <li><a href="#">Cores conecta</a></li>

        <li><a href="#">Miembros</a>
         <ul>
                      <li><a href="#">sujetos obligados</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Info cores</a></li>

                </ul>
            </li>

        <li><a href="#">Novedades</a>
         <ul>
                      <li><a href="#">Desde CORES</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Calendario Eventos</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Área corporativa</a></li>                      
                </ul>
            </li>                  
</ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Por acaso tem como deixar o css/js do que tem para isso? Ou postar també, no jsfiddle por exemplo?

Comment: E só de ver da para perceber que você não esta fechando o `<ul class="menu">` e tem um `</nav>` onde deveria ser um `</ul>`.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cgPtw/

Comment: Acho que copiei mal o codigo

Comment: Você poderia postar na própria pergunta só os trechos do CSS relativos ao menu? Recomendo ainda a leitura deste artigo da central de ajuda: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Ja coloquei o trecho na pergunta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema é quando o rato passa por cima do elemento com class `.Galeria`. Baixe o `z-index` para forçar o rato a ver o menu.

Tentei isto e funcionou bem: http://jsfiddle.net/cgPtw/1/

```
.Galeria {
    position:absolute;
    top:200px;
    left:150px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```